# PHP json_encode creates number index as string instead of an object

Tags: php, json

I have the following example code in PHP:

```
$data = array(
 'hello',
 'world',
 'hi'
);

$ret = array();
$ret['test'] = array();
$ret['testing'] = array();

foreach($data as $index => $value){
  if($index < 1){
      $ret['test'][$index]['val'] = $value;
      $ret['test'][$index]['me'] = 'index < 1';
  }
  else {
      $ret['testing'][$index]['val'] = $value;
      $ret['testing'][$index]['me'] = 'index >= 1';
  }
}

echo json_encode($ret);
```

I would expect this to be the JSON output:

```
[{
  "test":[
    {
       "val": "hello",
       "me": "index < 1"
    }
  ],
  "testing":[
    {
       "val": "world",
       "me": "index >= 1"   
    },
    {
       "val": "hi",
       "me": "index >= 1"
    }
  ]
}]
```

However, what ends up happening is that I end up with the following:

```
[{
  "test":[
    {
       "val": "hello",
       "me": "index < 1"
    }
  ],
  "testing":{
    "1":{
       "val": "world",
       "me": "index >= 1"   
    },
    "2":{
       "val": "hi",
       "me": "index >= 1"
    }
  }
}]
```

The `"1"` and `"2"` keys appear despite being an `int` and despite the correct rendering of `test` when the same counter variable is used. Is there a way I can make sure that `testing` becomes an array of JSON objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the array doesn't start with index `0` but with index `1`, it's encoded as an JSON object instead of an JSON array.

You can use the `array_values()` function to remove the indexes and only keep the values.

Example:

```
$ret['testing'] = array_values($ret['testing'])
echo json_encode($ret);
```

But because you don't need the index at this moment, you can also refactor your code to this:

```
foreach($data as $index => $value){
  if($index < 1){
    $ret['test'][] = array(
      'val' => $value,
      'me' => 'index < 1'
    );
  }
  else {
    $ret['testing'][] = array(
      'val' => $value,
      'me' => 'index >= 1'
    );
  }
}
echo json_encode($ret);
```

This way, the arrays will always start with index `0`.